# What happens to Kylo Ren's mask at the end of the movie?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren

Is there any information in the novel about what happens to his mask? Because the last time I saw it was left behind on the planet that was later destroyed.

Comment: WGA script doesn't mention the mask after he takes it off to have a family reunion with his father. However - seeing how he doesn't need it for fancy medical reasons like Vader - I'm pretty sure making a replacement isn't exactly a grand challenge for him should he decide he needs one.

Comment: Probably the same thing that happens to Kylo Ren.

Comment: It would be really cool if he would get a new costume, they could use one of the old concept arts made for Kylo Ren  (https://www.google.com.bo/search?q=concept+art+kylo+ren&client=ms-android-hms-tef-bo&prmd=ivn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimutHe6prKAhVJmR4KHdeRAr0Q_AUIBygB&biw=360&bih=511&dpr=2#imgrc=JECx-_3WEhB7fM%3A) (https://www.google.com.bo/search?q=concept+art+kylo+ren&client=ms-android-hms-tef-bo&prmd=ivn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimutHe6prKAhVJmR4KHdeRAr0Q_AUIBygB&biw=360&bih=511&dpr=2#imgrc=JECx-_3WEhB7fM%3A)

Comment: What is the likelihood that the First Order even *has the technology required to replicate a mask*? I mean... is that even possible? ;P

Comment: @DVK He _didn't_ need a mask for fancy medical reasons, but that might have changed after his light-sabre duel with Rey.

Comment: His mask survived. It's made of an alloy of Adamantium and Vibranium, so a Sun can't destroy it.

Comment: There's a really nice irony to the fact that, in the moment he though he was destroying the Ben side of himself for good and becoming the masked villain, actually, he loses his mask...

Comment: @user568458 There are a lot of nice ironies to Kylo.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9NKHySA4wQ This question needed answering; mask is, indeed, the mighty power that will save the day.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## The mask is probably space dust.  He will almost certainly fashion a new one, given the dress code of the Knights of Ren and the role that the mask serves.

His mask was almost certainly destroyed.  During his confrontation with Han, Kylo clunked the helmet down onto the catwalk of the oscillator unit of Starkiller Base.  He didn't carry it out of the unit, and the unit was completely destroyed.  Then the planet itself was obliterated.  The mask had little chance of surviving.

It is safe to say that Kylo Ren will fashion a new mask for himself.  Of the seven Knighs of Ren we have seen so far, at least six wear masks (the second from the right in the image below may or may not be wearing one):

[image]

Furthermore, Kylo sees great power in masks, using Vader's helmet in own his meditations as a way of channeling Vader's darkness:

[image]

Finally, as J.J. Abrams himself says:

> ***"Kylo Ren idolizes Darth Vader, not Anakin Skywalker."***

([Source](http://www.ign.com/videos/2015/12/18/jj-abrams-explains-why-kylo-ren-turned-to-the-dark-side))

Kylo has probably made an analogy involving masks: without his mask, he is just Ben Solo, who he describes as

> ***"weak and foolish"***

when confronting Han, much like Vader is merely Anakin Skywalker without his.

**From this point of view, the mask is integral to Kylo Ren's identity.**

Comment: Note that I say "probably" and "little chance" --- I'm not completely rejecting the idea that Kylo Ren's mask from Episode 7 might turn up in a mangled state in Episode 10 or 11 in the room of some angst-filled grandchild of Leia.

Comment: Great answer for my first question in the site. Thank you. I hope he gets a cooler mask.

Comment: @user58935 : You're welcome.  I also think that he could do with a cooler mask...

Comment: Someone should write an essay on how the empire & first order use mask-work in their training...

Comment: His mask is made of an alloy of Adamantium and Vibranium, it should still be intact.

Comment: @SS-3 : Hehe, but I thought Disney doesn't have the rights to adamantium!  ;-)