# Why is Kylo Ren's Helmet so Heavy?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren

In the new Star Wars movie we see Kylo Ren take off his helmet twice. Both times there is a loud "thud" and the camera focuses on the helmet's impact, as if to reinforce that Kylo Ren's helmet is heavy. *Unreasonably heavy.*

Is there any reason given for the weight of the helmet? As we see in the Star Wars universe, bulky helmets (looking at you Fett), don't do much. Even armour is pretty weak against laser blasters and lightsabers. Kylo Ren's other armour seems pretty lacklustre and light compared to the bulky helmet; barely stopping the three injuries he sustains in *The Force Awakens*. The weight of the helmet would seem to be a hindrance, at best, in combat.

Comment: I'm not really sure what answer you could be looking for here. It's made of a heavier material or some components are heavy? Of course the *thud* could just be the movie being dramatic.

Comment: KR doesn't skip neck day.

Comment: Voting to leave open.  Not sure it's a *good* question, and the answer might be as simple as "No, no reason.", but the question is clear.

Comment: I agree that this is in no way unclear. I’d even say it’s a good question. We know for a fact (though I’m not sure what level of canon we’re in) that there is a very specific reason for Darth Vader’s costume and helmet being heavy and oppressive to wear—it’s not far-fetched at all that there should be a reason behind Kylo Ren’s, too.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - it even makes me wonder why he wears a helmet at all.  Darth V *needed* to wear one.  I wonder if it's a kind of Darth Vader hero-worship, or makes him feel "stronger" in front of others.  He certainly doesn't *need* it.

Comment: @Mikey Anonymity-by-helmet does make you seem more intimidating and frightening, though.

Comment: plus, if he didn't wear the helmet everyone would laugh at his silly crooked face and whiney demeanor. Maybe the thickness or weight of the material shields him from something... or boosts

Comment: @Mikey *Re: why he wears a helmet* --- see my answer to [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/114165/40294).

Comment: The main purpose of the question is that Kylo Ren could wear a light weight, allumnium helmet with some spay paint but the movies twice makes the audience focus on the weight of helmet. If it was relevant enough for the camera....

Answer (score 2):

Living in the shadow of perhaps the most significant sith of the dark side is a heavy burden. The helmet is an analogy.