# Is Kylo Ren's mask instrumented?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren

We have seen during the movie that Kylo Ren's mask is [really heavy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117761/why-is-kylo-rens-helmet-so-heavy).

We also can guess that the primary reason Kylo Ren wears his mask is to mark his link with the Knights of Ren, as an intimidation tool and as an homage to Darth Vader.([Why does Kylo Ren wear a mask?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111174/why-does-kylo-ren-wear-a-mask))

But do we know if Kylo Ren's mask actually has any internal function, besides the obvious Voice Changer?

Does it have an HUD that gets displayed in front of the wearer's eyes?
Does it have some sort of built-in function to communicate with other people such as stormtroopers?

Comment: good question, he might have Jarvis in there too.

Comment: Wookiepedia's entry for Kylo only mentioned that the mask changes his voice. If any official source mentions any other function, the article doesn't cite it. Remember that Kylo is a Vader worshipper that is physically healthy and in one piece. From his perspective, he probably only needs a mask that lets him "be Vader" in front of others. Any non-critical function that doesn't serve that purpose is probably minimal or non-existant - the dark side provides him with what he needs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is **no**.  As shown in a diagram in the official visual dictionary (canon), Kylo Ren's mask has three functions:

- "Integrated vocabulator *projects* Ren's voice." (emphasis added)
- "Silver inlay radiates from the eyes as a symbol of power."
- "Kylo Ren's helmet *conceals his identity* and adds to his imposing demeanor." (emphasis added)

Shown in the visual dictionary for the original trilogy, Darth Vader's *very* instrumented mask contains explicit tools to help him survive. ("Respiratory vent", "respiratory intake", "Vision enhancement receptors")

Based on this, we can conclude that Kylo Ren's mask, though functional, is not enhanced with any special instruments.