# How exactly does Kylo Ren's voice changer work?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Related: [Is Kylo Ren's mask instrumented?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117847/is-kylo-rens-mask-instrumented)

The answer to the above question mentions that Ren's helmet contains an "integrated vocabulator" that changes and projects his voice.  But how does that component actually work?  Is this simply a passive acoustic device or is it, say, battery-powered?  We know the mask is not instrumented but that doesn't necessarily mean anything about the voice changer itself.

(I'm looking for the in-universe answer.  Out-of-universe, I'm certain that it was an electronic effect used to dub over everything Adam Driver said while in costume.)

Comment: *How exactly does Kylo Ren's voice changer work?* Very well, thank you!

Comment: Very emo-like..

Comment: Totally non-canon (but amusing nonetheless): https://youtu.be/nFicXlvJBdo    There's a scene where the voice changer malfunctions.

Comment: Probably a more advanced version of the toys that we've had on earth for decades.

Comment: https://www.walmart.com/ip/Star-Wars-The-Empire-Strikes-Back-Darth-Vader-Voice-Changer-Helmet/46203099?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=3351&adid=22222222227034038860&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=72202716032&wl4=pla-140125990112&wl5=9026920&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=113553737&wl11=online&wl12=46203099&wl13=&veh=sem

Answer (score 1):

The fact that Kylo Ren wears a helmet is directly related to the fact that he is fascinated with every aspect about his grandfather, Darth Vader. Even though he doesn't need one to survive, taking a look at all of the other helmets across the movies, it's easy to determine that it has several features. The "integrated vocabulator" could be just a part of a communication system, similar to the Stormtroopers' helmets. This would allow him to also have communication on a battlefield.

The fact that his voice was changed would mirror Vader's helmet, which changed his voice as well. It could be just as simple as changing the voice as it's transmitted outside of the helmet, just like stormtroopers or Vader, but there could also allow for encrypted communication, just like the stormtroopers at the beginning of "Rogue One"